# How to move Collection<Double> values greater than 0 to decimal places

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, double, decimal

I want to move every value greater than 0 to one decimal place for `Collection<Double>`, how would I do that?

Where single units are moved 3 decimal places, tens are moved 2 decimal places and hundreds are moved 1 decimal place.

For example:

```
//an array like this
[140, 23, 3]

//should be
[0.140, 0.023, 0.003]
```

The script I am using counts the amount of times a particular String appears, though I'm unsure how to approach the above with `Collection<Double>`:

```
public class doubleTest {

HashMap<String, Double> texted(String tex) {
        

        HashMap<String, Double> counts = new HashMap<String, Double>();

        for (String word : tex.split(" ")) { // loops through each word of the string
            // text.split(" ") returns an array, with all the parts of the string between your regexes
            // if current word is not already in the map, add it to the map.

            if (!counts.containsKey(word)) counts.put(word, (double) 0);

            counts.put(word,counts.get(word) + 1); // adds one to the count of the current word

        }
return counts;
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final   String text = "Win Win Win Win Draw Draw Loss Loss";
        
        textSplit countWords = new textSplit();
        
        HashMap<String, Double> result = countWords.texted(text);
        

       Collection<Double> resultD = result.values();

      for(int i = 0; i<resultD.size();i++){
            double[] value = new double[]{i*0.001};
Collection<Double> valuet = Arrays.stream(value).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        System.out.println(valuet);

//output
//[0.0]
//[0.001]
//[0.002]

     
      
  
                   }


        //System.out.println(resultD);
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't see how "counts the amount of times a particular String appears" is related to moving the numbers in a `Collection<Double>` by some decimal places... You seem  to be talking about very different things here.

Comment: Just multiply each value by 0.001.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc How do I store `0.001` as `Colection<Double>`?

Comment: Multiply 140 by 0.001, giving 0.14.  Store 0.14 in your Collection<Double>.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Given that the numerical value is stored by the number of times a string is counted, would you suggest that I multiply the number of times the string is counted by `0.001`, would that work?

Comment: I obviously don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Could you please explain what 140 represents, what 0.14 represents, and why in excruciating detail you want to go from 140 to 0.14?  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The array provided is only an example, however, the script below produces the same array with different values and they're called as `Collection<Double>`. I cannot simply multiply the array by `0.001` unless it's perhaps within a for-loop though I wouldn't know how to approach this loop with `Collection<Double>`, how would I store a variable i.e. `i` within the collection? The aim is as the title mentions, to move the units by three decimal places to the right.

Comment: double value = i * 0.001;  Store value in Collkections<Double>  I don't understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have tried doing what you have mentioned, however, I can seem to only store the size of the collection into `value` as opposed to the collection values from `resultD`. How would I be able to do what I have mentioned? Given that creating the `Collection<Double>` requires an array, unless there's an alternative I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler way of doing this is using the map() function.

Logic:- Multipy each element of array with 0.001

```
public class Test2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(140,23,3);
     Collection<Double> collection;
     collection = list.stream().map(x ->  x* .001).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
     System.out.println(collection);
 }
}
```

**Output**

[0.14, 0.023, 0.003]